# How to do a simple circular queue of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, priority-queue

I would like to make two classes. One (`class Mover`) is changing the fields that other(`class Window`) is using to repaint something every `1/30 seconds`. I would like to make them work interchangeably(Mover,Window,Mover,Window,Mover,Window,Mover,Window...). `Mover` is calculating while `Window` is waiting then `Mover` is waiting while `Window` is repainting.

I was looking for Queue of threads which would work like

`q.next(); next thread is awakening and the current is going to the end to wait`

but didn't find any. How to do it in the simplest way.

**There will be many movers and one window.**

Comment: probably you should tell what you want to calculate

Comment: there's no need to run the tasks using separate threads

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying solve producer-consumer sort of problem. May be you can synchronize the Mover/Window on some common lock and then use wait/notify feature. Something like below

```
class Lock {
  public static Lock INSTANCE = new Lock();
}

class Mover {

  public void move() {
    synchronized(Lock.INSTANCE) {
       //do the move
       Lock.INSTANCE.notifyAll();
       Lock.INSTANCE.wait();
    }
  }

}

class Window {

  public void paint() {
    synchronized(Lock.INSTANCE) {
       //do the paint
       Lock.INSTANCE.notifyAll();
       Lock.INSTANCE.wait();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: With no loop, why wait() at the end anyway?

Comment: @Timmy: Because paint() is called in another loop : the GUI loop

Comment: @Aubin Threads can be awake from Object.wait() without a reason. [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()).

Answer (score 0):

Since the tasks are supposed to run interchangeably, there's no need to run the tasks using separate threads as it's hard to get concurrency right. Use a ScheduledExecutorService to run the logic periodically, in a single thread.

```
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ses.schedule(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            mover.run();
            window.run();
        }
    }, 1000/30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: +1: ` there's no need to run the tasks using separate threads`, -1: No, windows have their own thread. paint() can't be called from run()

Comment: @RobertKilar Is the Window class under your control? Is it running on a separate thread that calls repaint() periodically?